# ChromExtension: SidePanel track down the tab changes and render on sidepanel UI

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v2

I have a case where I want to track down the click on action item under sidepanel
The below code

```
chrome.sidePanel
  .setPanelBehavior({ openPanelOnActionClick: true }).addListener(callback)
```

throws error

```
Uncaught TypeError: chrome.sidePanel.setPanelBehavior(...).addListener is not a function
```

How can I track the callback for the case where a user comes in and click on the action button and sidepanel extension opens up which will then in background fetch specific elements from the current tab webpage (which I have already wrote down) and then display those elements content on the sidepanel UI
This needs to be done on every tab change

Comment: setPanelBehavior returns a void Promise, so you can't use addListener on it. Generally you can simply use chrome.tabs.onUpdated and chrome.tabs.onActivated in your sidePanel js script, not in the background script (service worker).